# I don't know why I'm getting this error in full join in MySql

Tags: mysql, outer-join

select w.fname,w.salary, t.worker_title from Worker w full join Title t on w.worker_id=t.worker_ref_id;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'full join Title t on w.worker_id=t.worker_ref_id' at line 1

Comment: MYSQL does not support FULL JOIN , google mysql full join for alternates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want result of full ouret join then use below way:

```
SELECT  p.LastName, p.FirstName, o.OrderNo
FROM    persons AS p
LEFT JOIN
        orders AS o
ON      o.orderNo = p.p_id
UNION ALL
SELECT  NULL, NULL, orderNo
FROM    orders
WHERE   orderNo NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  p_id
        FROM    persons
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude try worker as w INNER JOIN title as t